# Disable [base] repository in CentOS-Base.repo

Tags: repository, centos

I want to disable base repository in centos-base.repo with help of nano, but don't know how to do it. 
Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nano /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and then you can search the base repo by checking the tags given in `[]`. So for base repo edit the section with `[base]` .

In that section you need to add the following tag:

```
enabled=0
```